# Oracle database - how to conditionally select the one row of two rows from a result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data in an Oracle table:

```
Date             Amount  Flag
12/09/2018 0:00  191     1
12/09/2018 0:00  190     0
13/09/2018 0:00  187     0
14/09/2018 0:00  200     1
14/09/2018 0:00  201     0
```

I would like to retrieve all records that have a 0 flag, and if there is a duplicate row that has a flag of 1, it should take preference. So the end result of the above table should look like this:

```
Date             Amount Flag
12/09/2018 0:00  191    1
13/09/2018 0:00  187    0
14/09/2018 0:00  200    1
```

Comment: What is the criteria for deciding duplicate rows?

Comment: the datetime should be unique. If two rows have the same datetime, then the row with the flag value of 1 should be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (cdate, amount, flag) as
  2  (select date '2018-09-12', 191, 1 from dual union all
  3   select date '2018-09-12', 190, 0 from dual union all
  4   select date '2018-09-13', 187, 0 from dual union all
  5   select date '2018-09-14', 200, 1 from dual union all
  6   select date '2018-09-14', 201, 0 from dual
  7  )
  8  select cdate, amount, flag
  9  from (select cdate, amount, flag,
 10               row_number() over (partition by cdate order by flag desc) rn
 11        from test
 12       )
 13  where rn = 1;

CDATE          AMOUNT       FLAG
---------- ---------- ----------
12/09/2018        191          1
13/09/2018        187          0
14/09/2018        200          1

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, uses less code and as you mentioned is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
select * from <<table>> outer where outer.flag= 1 
and exists  (select * from <<table>> inner where inner.flag = 0 and inner.date=outer.date) 
UNION 
select * from <<table>> outer where outer.flag= 0 and 
not exists  (select * from <<table>> inner where inner.flag = 1 and inner.date=outer.date) ;
```

Comment: @noobie, note that this is probably quite inefficient solution as it scans <<table>> 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
SELECT date, amount, flag
FROM tableName
HAVING flag = MAX(flag)
GROUP BY date, amount,flag
```

Comment: I don't think this query is syntactically correct :/

Comment: Tried it with the HAVING clause after the GROUP BY, but does still returns duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You could try first retrieving all records with a flag of 1, then looking for all records with flag of 0 that don't appear in the first set of retrieved records:

```
SELECT * FROM flags WHERE flag = 1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM flags WHERE flag = 0 
AND flagdate NOT IN (SELECT flagdate FROM flags WHERE flag = 1);
```

This works with the sample data.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69dc02/2